# Please help in installing xlwt using pip in Python

Tags: python

I got some help on a question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264768/an-error-message-importerror-no-module-named-xlwt, installing pip.

but may I know what the "pip install xlwt" means? i check the folder C:\Python27\pip-1.4.1 and there's nothing like xlwt. and I tried typed "pip install xlwt" in Python Shell it also doesn't work.

Please help me and sorry for not asking smart questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt, extract the contents of the folder and then copy the folder named **xlwt** to **C:\Python27\Lib**. This manual approach should help out.